# react-search box -> Functionality not working while calling the map function

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import Heading from "../src/components/Heading";
    import Info from "./Info";
    import Card from "../src/components/Cards";
    
    function createCard(Info) {
      return <Card key={Info.id} name={Info.name} />;
    }
    
    function App() {
      const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    
      const findperson = Info.filter( personName=> {
        return personName.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase);
      });
    
      return (
        <div>
         
          <Heading />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search"
            onChange={event => setSearch(event.target.value)}
          />
          {findperson.map(createCard)}
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default App;
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Array info.js
```

```
const Info = [
     {
       id: 1,
       name: "Rahul"
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       name: "Rohan"
     },
     {
       id: 3,
       name: "rajesh"
     }
   ];
   
   export default Info;
```

I am trying to make a search-box that fetches data from an array (info) and then filters the data , However while calling the map function my code is breaking and i am not able to display any data ,

[console log for findPerson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHKZh.png)

Comment: If i simply use `Info.map(createCard)` the code displays the cards but after adding the filter function all functionality is lost

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling toLowerCase, instead you are passing the function itself.

```
  const findperson = Info.filter( personName=> {
    // return personName.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase);
    return personName.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()); // <-- () missing
  });
```

Comment: I added your suggestion  still there is no output in  display , if i just map the array using `Info.map(createCard) i can see the infomation but after adding the filter function the array dissapears and there is only a unfunctional searchbox

Comment: That means findperson is always an empty array? what do you get when you log findperson?

Comment: while console log (findperson) i can find the  object containing id and name

Comment: Although i feel like there should be some code after  `{findperson.map(createCard)}` that adds the previous array also along with what comes if the search bar is used

Comment: So findPerson logs something like this: [{ id: 1, name: 'Rahul'}], but when map over it it doesn't return any Card?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time trying to understand where the issue is because i cant really debug, but here is a working example as demonstration on how i would do it, maybe that helps.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";

const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Hamilton"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Bruce"
  }
];

const Item = ({ name, id }) => {
  return <div>{name}</div>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  
  const filteredItems = useMemo(() => {
    return items.filter(i => search === "" || i.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input value={search} onChange={ e => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
      {
        filteredItems.map(Item)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```